# Basement Rough In Decipher

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement, rough-in

[image]

Can someone help me decipher the rough in currently in our basement and identify what is what? What else needs to be done to complete the rough in before finishing the bathroom and starting to frame?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to DIY SE. Unfortunately your question is rather vague. What specifically are you asking about in the photo, and what are you roughing in? You may want to break the subject out into several distinct questions. Please see the help pages if you are not clear on what's expected of you.

Comment: Where's the toilet flange? That fat pipe coming out of the floor might be where it goes, but it's right where they anticipated putting a sink, so... (prob supposed to be an overflow floor drain) Also, I've no idea what the little pipe in the floor is for. And... framing is first, always. What's behind the insulation?

Comment: The little one is for a shower or tub? More pictures plz. Are those doors just standing there?

Comment: I’m not sure what’s behind the insulation - this is what it was like when we moved in. I assumed the toilet drain was the wider pipe but confused as to why the sink drain would be directly behind it.. Is it possible to frame after insulation? Or would the insulation have to be ripped out first? Confused as to what they did here!

Comment: Added 2 more pictures.. and the doors are just there for storage, not attached to anything

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This all needs to be confirmed, it is an educated guess.